# How would you use multicol with the default pandoc latex template?

Tags: multicol, pandoc

Pandoc's default latex output works well for my use-case, but I would like the body to be in two columns. I've tried editing the default template, generated with `pandoc -D latex`, by updating the preamble to:

```
...
\usepackage{pgfpages, multicol}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }
...
```

and the main section to:

```
...
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\mainmatter
$endif$
\begin{multicols}{2}
$body$
\end{multicols}
...
```

but that's getting me the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Environment multicols undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.79 \begin{multicols}
```

I've tried verifying the environment name with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and that works fine, but I'm not familiar enough with Latex or Pandoc to really know why the `muilticols` environment is undefined if I edit the pandoc template. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You did put the statement to load the `multicol` package in a conditional that is only processes when beamer is used. Just load it somewhere else, e.g. above `$if(beamer)$`

Comment: I didn't realise that the load statement was inside $if(beamer)$, thanks for pointing that out! Moving `\usepackage{muilticol}` to above `$if(beamer)$`, and directly under the `\documentclass` statement gives a new error: `! Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode. ... l.331 \begin{longtable}`, but `\begin{longtable}` isn't being called directly in the latex, so I'm not sure where that's coming from

Comment: This looks like a new and different issue. You could export to latex to debug it there and then ask new questions about the issues that arise. Anyway: Longtable does not work in multiple column formats (see sec. 9.5 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)).

Comment: There are already filters like https://github.com/dialoa/columns to make things easier

Comment: There is a workaround, using `tabularry` instead of `longtable`: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7475#issuecomment-1829790171

Comment: Using the columns filter made things a lot easier. I realised that it's a markdown table that's causing `\begin{longtable}` to be called, and it doesn't seem to like putting the `longtable` within a `multicols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `multicol` for two columns document, is better use the `twocolumn` option that have not problems with  floats.

Unfortunately, markdown tables are exported as long tables that are not floats, and worse, as you discover, they  cannot be used in multicols nor with the twocolumn option.

However, without filters or extensions, using Quarto markdown (save the MWE with the `.qmd` extension) you can use these workarounds, each with its own disadvantages:

[image: mwe]

````
---
format: pdf
keep-tex: true
classoption: twocolumn
include-in-header: 
- text: \usepackage{lipsum}
---

See @tbl-foo and Table \ref{tbl-x} and @tbl-lt

# Option: Insert true LaTeX tabulars

\lipsum[1][1-3]

::: {#tbl-foo tbl-pos="h"}

```{=tex}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
a & b \\
\end{tabular}
```
This is the caption

:::


# Option: R/phyton generated tables

\lipsum[2][1-3]

```{r}
#| results: asis
#| echo: false
#| tbl-cap: This is a xtable

df <- data.frame(Foo=c(1,2,3),Bar=c("foo","bar","baz"))
library(xtable)
print(xtable(df, label="tbl-x"), floating=T, comment=F, table.placement = "h")

```


# Option 4: Redefine longtable

\lipsum[3][1-3]

```{=tex}

% of course, better in the preamble

\makeatletter
\let\oldlt\longtable
\let\endoldlt\endlongtable
\def\longtable{\@ifnextchar[\longtable@i \longtable@ii}
\def\longtable@i[#1]{\begin{table}[h]
\onecolumn
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\oldlt[#1]
}
\def\longtable@ii{\begin{table}
\onecolumn

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\oldlt
}
\def\endlongtable{\endoldlt
\end{minipage}
\twocolumn
\end{table}
}
\makeatother
```

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
| foo  | bar  | baz  |
| tic  | tac  | toe  |

: This is the caption {#tbl-lt}

\lipsum[4-7]
````

Comment: Nice use of quarto +1